# Subquery in LINQ that's in the select statement, not the where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, subquery

I need to do something like the following

```
SELECT p.name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM products WHERE products.parent_id = p.id) AS sub_products
FROM products AS p
```

I see lots of LINQ examples of subqueries in the where clause,but nothing like this where it's in the select statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should be equivalent:

```
var query = Products.Select(p => new {
                         p.Name,
                         SubProducts = Products.Count(c => c.parent_id == p.id)
                     });

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Name, item.SubProducts);
}
```

Comment: Note that using subqueries in select don't work for me in LinqPad but works from a C# project.

Comment: @eka808 that's odd, it works fine for me and I've never run into such a limitation. Perhaps you can post a question about it.