# using Min and Max function in this LINQ query with joins?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am making a LINQ query which is join of multiple tables. In result set I want to ad a column which shows Min and Max date combinely **[e.g.(20/3/2012 - 25/4/2012)]** from table.

The structure of table (which is a table to manage many to many relationship) from where I want to pick date is as below:

```
BookedAreaID    int
AreaID  int
LeasedDate  datetime
InvoiceID   int
```

Here is my LINQ query:

```
var selectedResults=
from InvoiceSet in Invoices
join BookedAreaSet in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreaSet.InvoiceID
join AreaSet in Areas on BookedAreaSet.AreaID equals AreaSet.AreaID
join ContactSet in Contacts on InvoiceSet.ContactID equals ContactSet.ContactID
join Contacts_ObjectsSet in Contacts_Objects on ContactSet.ContactID  equals Contacts_ObjectsSet.ContactID
join CompanySet in Companies on Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReferenceID  equals  CompanySet.CompanyID
join BookedAreasSet in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID

where Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReference=="Company"

select new {InvoiceSet.InvoiceNumber,InvoiceSet.Amount,InvoiceSet.TotalDiscount,InvoiceSet.GST,
InvoiceSet.PaymentDate,InvoiceSet.ShoppingCentreID,BookedAreasSet.BookedAreaID,AreaSet.Name,Paid=(InvoiceSet.PaymentDate==null ? "UnPaid":"Paid"), 
licensee=(CompanySet.CompanyName))
};
```

I want to select something like with this query:

```
DateRange=
(Min(BookedAreasSet.LeasedDate where BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID=InvoiceSet.InvoiceID) 
+ "-" + 
Max(BookedAreasSet.LeasedDate where BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID=InvoiceSet.InvoiceID)
```

Comment: You can do this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098375/subquery-in-linq-thats-in-the-select-statement-not-the-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're joining twice on this condition BTW:

"join BookedAreasSet in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID"

Can't you just use?

```
DateRange=
(Min(BookedAreasSet.LeasedDate) 
+ "-" + 
Max(BookedAreasSet.LeasedDate))
```